# How do I write all of this in assembly

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly, x86

I have two macros, one is written in assembly and the other in C. The second macro uses the first macro. However, I also want to write the second macro in assembly with volatile, so I can control its placement in the code. And please note that **tid** is a runtime value, not a constant like **n**.

What is a good way to write that in assembly? Also, is it possible to control placement of a C code like assembly with volatile?

```
#define SAVE_SP(n) __asm__ __volatile__ ("movq %rsp, msp"#n";" \
     "movq ts"#n", %rsp;" \
     )

#define SAVE_STACK_POINTER( tid ) \
    switch( tid ) \
    { \
        case 0: \
            SAVE_SP( 0 ); \
            break; \
        case 1: \
            SAVE_SP( 1 ); \
            break; \
        case 2: \
            SAVE_SP( 2 ); \
            break; \
        case 3: \
            SAVE_SP( 3 ); \
            break; \
    }
```

Comment: tid is a runtime value, not a constant like n.

Comment: (Never mind, that was nonsense.)

Comment: Is it possible to store the `tsp<n>` and `msp<n>` values in an array?

Comment: Which compiler/assembler are you using? For which processor? Inline assembler is not standardized, so the syntax to use C variables in inline assembly is highly dependent on those choices.

Comment: Why is SAVE_STACK_POINTER called at all, instead of calling SAVE_SP directly?

Comment: @Jim, because tid is not a constant and not known at compile time.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the point of your first comment.  I get it now.

Comment: Are `mspN` and `tsN` global variables, or are they special registers that my assembler doesn't know about?

Comment: Since you're doing it in a dirty way, why not at least use `setjmp()/longjmp()`? Find out where the registers are inside of `jmp_buf` and use that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ask gcc its idea of how to write your code in assembly: `gcc -S foo.c` or `gcc -Wa,-alh=foo.s -c foo.c`. You may want to improve on the results, of course. You will need to do a little extra: use `%0` for the parameter that you pass for the assembly chunk, and declare the registers that you've clobbered. Look up [Assembler Instructions with C Expression Operands in the GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm) if you aren't familiar. Here's how this might look like (warning, typed directly into the browser, and don't really know x86 assembly syntax).

```
#define SAVE_STACK_POINTER(tid) __asm__ __volatile__ (" \
        cmpl $0, %0                                   \n\
        je .SAVE_STACK_POINTER_0                      \n\
        cmpl $1, %0                                   \n\
        je .SAVE_STACK_POINTER_1                      \n\
        cmpl $2, %0                                   \n\
        je .SAVE_STACK_POINTER_2                      \n\
        cmpl $3, %0                                   \n\
        je .SAVE_STACK_POINTER_3                      \n\
        jmp .SAVE_STACK_POINTER_done                  \n\
      .SAVE_STACK_POINTER_0:                          \n\
        movq %%rsp, msp0                              \n\
        movq ts0, %%rsp                               \n\
        jmp SAVE_STACK_POINTER_done                   \n\
      .SAVE_STACK_POINTER_1:                          \n\
        movq %%rsp, msp1                              \n\
        movq ts1, %%rsp                               \n\
        jmp SAVE_STACK_POINTER_done                   \n\
      .SAVE_STACK_POINTER_2:                          \n\
        movq %%rsp, msp2                              \n\
        movq ts2, %%rsp                               \n\
        jmp SAVE_STACK_POINTER_done                   \n\
      .SAVE_STACK_POINTER_3:                          \n\
        movq %%rsp, msp3                              \n\
        movq ts3, %%rsp                               \n\
      .SAVE_STACK_POINTER_done:                       \n\
    " : : "r" (tid))
```

A fancier method would involve figuring out how many bytes each `movq`-`movq`-`jmp` block takes (note: I haven't checked, I use 8) and making a computed jump into it; something like

```
__asm__("                        \n\
    movl %0, %eax                \n\
    mul  8, %eax                 \n\
    add  4, %eax                 \n\
    jmp . + %eax                 \n\
    movq %%rsp, msp0             \n\
    movq ts0, %%rsp              \n\
    jmp .SAVE_STACK_POINTER_done \n\
    …
  .SAVE_STACK_POINTER_done:      \n\
" : : "r" (tid) : "%eax")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using GCC, you could try to use a GNU extension to map the stack pointer register to a C variable:

```
static register int stack_pointer0 asm("msp0");

void myfn () {
  ......
  saved_stack_pointer = stack_pointer0;
  ......
}
```

OK, that probably doesn't do what your original code did (it wasn't clear to me what the goal was), but you should be able to figure out the rest from that.

I think I got the syntax right, but apologies if not. I know this works for general registers, and I'm pretty confident GCC knows what to do for special registers, but you never know.

Hope that helps.